# Update TextBox allowing decimal in real time using serial csv data string array as input

Tags: c#

I have 16 TextBox. Each TextBox should be updated with values (separated by comma).

```
public string DataReceived
{
    get { return data_str; }
    set
    {                
        data_str = value;
        string[] valori_separati = DataReceived.Split(',');
        //valori_separati = DataReceived.Split(',');
         try
         {               
             int.TryParse(valori_separati[0], out Team_ID);
             int.TryParse(valori_separati[1], out Mission_time);
             double.TryParse(valori_separati[2], out Packet_count);
             int.TryParse(valori_separati[3], out Alt_sensor);
             double.TryParse(valori_separati[4], out Pressure);
             double.TryParse(valori_separati[5], out Temp);
             double.TryParse(valori_separati[6], out Voltage);
             double.TryParse(valori_separati[7], out GPS_Time);
             double.TryParse(valori_separati[8], out GPS_Latitude);
             double.TryParse(valori_separati[9], out GPS_Longitude);
             double.TryParse(valori_separati[10], out GPS_Altitude);
             int.TryParse(valori_separati[11], out GPS_Sats);
             double.TryParse(valori_separati[12], out TILT_X);
             double.TryParse(valori_separati[13], out TILT_Y);
             double.TryParse(valori_separati[14], out TILT_Z);
             int.TryParse(valori_separati[15], out Software_state);
         }
         catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
         {
             packet_loss = packet_loss + 1;
         }
         if (packet_loss >= 5)
         {
             BeginInvoke((Action)(() => fr1.Show()));
         }
        updateTextboxDelegate fillTextbox = updateTextbox;
        this.Invoke(fillTextbox);
    }
}
private void updateTextbox()
{
    Data_ID_Glider.Text = Team_ID.ToString();
    DataMssTime.Text = Mission_time.ToString();
    Data_Pack.Text = Packet_count.ToString();
    Data_Alt.Text = Alt_sensor.ToString();
    Data_Press.Text = Pressure.ToString();
    GpsTime.Text = GPS_Time.ToString();
    Data_Temp.Text = Temp.ToString();
    Data_Voltage.Text = Voltage.ToString();
    Data_Sw_St.Text = Software_state.ToString();
    [...]
   }
```

By this way decimal values are not shown. I mean that only numbers, without their decimals, are shown. I tried to update the textbox inside the datareceived but thread exception is called. How should I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using this method:

```
double.TryParse(valori_separati[12],NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture ("en-US"), out TILT_X);
```

and so on with the other array arguments.

Answer (score 0):

After casting most of the values into double, you are using double.ToString() method to convert it into a string. This truncates the decimal part of the double value.

There are many string formatters that you can use to format the double value according to your needs.

For example you can try

```
Data_ID_Glider.Text = Team_ID.ToString("F");
```

The above will assign the value of Team_ID with 3 decimal places. For more such specifiers you can take a look here

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm going to try it  right now! i'll keep you updated!

Comment: I tried but unfortunately the decimal part of the number is shown before the decimal: i.e. 1.23 = 123.00

Comment: How about this then `Team_ID.ToString("F");`? You can try the various combinations mentioned in the link I've given and see which one you need

Comment: I tried actually with each one of the solution proposed, but i still receive the same kind of value

Comment: It seems that the Fullstop(point for decimal part) is not seen by the code for the textbox.

Comment: Can you post an example of what input value is being converted into what output value?

Comment: Yes, of course. The input value is : 1246,1,1,30,1040,16,9,1,1,24.7,75.5,31,26,3,4,5. The output values are (as shown in textbox):1246 ; 1 ; 1 ; 30 ; 1040 ; 16 ; 9 ;1 ; 1 ; 247.00 ; 755.00 ; 31 ; 26 ; 3 ; 4 ; 5